# Novel about a mission to the edge of the solar system to find a lost ship; everyone on the missing ship is a zen acolyte; the protagonist joins them

Tags: story-identification, novel, space

I've got just one image from the book, which is at the very end: the protagonist, now joining the acolytes / cult-members on the missing ship, lies down in his newly assigned bunk, and his shaved head lands in the perfectly formed dent in the pillow, just like every other monk / cult-member / whatever who used the pillow before him.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: Could it be "Monks in space" by David Jones? I don't know any details of the book though.

Comment: Re publication date: I believe I read it before going off to college, so <= 1988.

Re "Monks in Space", no, I don't believe so.  Also, publication date is off by 20 years. :)